# Jenkins Performance Report Plugin does not fail step

Tags: jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I am using Maven to Run Jmetere and Jenkins Perfreport plugin using pipeline script to generate report. I have set threshold in the plugin but the report step does not fail(Even if it shows that threshold is reached ) and it only fails the build in the end. This causes problem as all the other steps after perf report executes which I dont want.
How do I make the build fail at the perf report step so that I can fail the build then and there. I only want to propagate the build if the perf report is pass which is causing problem as the perf step always passes and the final status of the build is set to fail

Comment: were you be able to solve a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven you should be able to fail the test on Maven task execution stage by adding the next stanza to your [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html):

```
<execution>
    <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>results</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

[image]

For the time being you can only manipulate [error percentage](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/jmeter/mojo/CheckResultsMojo.java#L44) (defaults to `0`) so if your "thresholds" are more complex you might want to switch from Maven to [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation/) which has quite powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria Subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/)

Comment: I have criteria that if any sample has a 90% response time of more than 500ms the build should fail.  Jenkins performance plugin is doing that but at the end after executing all the steps in the build